# Why isn't submit inputs and submit buttons submitted in form when using JavaScript to submit form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

`myform1` sends `button` with value `button-value` to the server, but `myform2` and `myform3` does not.  Why is this?

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST)){
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Testing</title>  
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $(function(){
                    $( "#myform2, #myform3" ).submit(function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log(this,$(this).find(":input,:button").serializeArray());
                        alert('submit')
                        this.submit();
                    });

                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="myform" id="myform1" method="post">
                <button value="button-value" name="button" type="submit">button</button>
                <input type="test" value="123" name="data">
            </form>
            <form name="myform" id="myform2" method="post">
                <button value="button-value" name="button" type="submit">button</button>
                <input type="test" value="123" name="data">
            </form>
            <form name="myform" id="myform3" method="post">
                <input value="button-value" name="button" type="submit">
                <input type="test" value="123" name="data">
            </form>
        </body> 
    </html> 
    <?php
}
else {echo('<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');}  
?>
```

Comment: you are entering an endless loop it looks like.

Comment: @DanielA.White  It does submit, but I only get `$_POST` equal to `Array([data] => 123)` at the server.

Comment: try giving different name attribute values to each textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms can have multiple submit buttons.  If you call a form's submit method, it can't infer which submit was used.  To get a submit input to register in a post, you have to actively use it to submit the form.  I can think of two ways around this.

#### Default value placed in a hidden input

You could add a default value in a `<input type="hidden">` field.  If the form is submitted programmatically, the hidden field is used for the value.  If the submit button is clicked manually, that will be used as it occurs later in the form.

```
        <form name="myform" id="myform2" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="button-value" name="button">
            <button value="button-value" name="button" type="submit">button</button>
            <input type="test" value="123" name="data">
        </form>
```

#### Trigger a `click` event instead of a `submit` event

You could also just trigger the click event of a form button, which will in turn trigger the `submit` of the form with the appropriate value in the POST.  With your current code this is less practical to put in an example because nomal submit (which would be triggered after the click event is triggered) is interrupted and prevented.

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  Right after I read your first sentence, I said "of course!".  I was just blinded and didn't see it at first.  The solutions were the easy part, but appreciate them never the less.  Thanks again!